# Prestashop backoffice module

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have created a Prestashop Backoffice module but on clicking module tab in menu , I am getting error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPBNu.png) 404 page not found?

I want to create a template on clicking module tab and display some text there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the entry of the back-office controller in the Menu. You can **use the following code** to add the controller in the tab:

For Prestashop 1.7:

```
    $parentTab->name = array();
    foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
        $parentTab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = $this->l('ShipRocket');
    }

    $parentTab->class_name = 'AdminShiprocket';
    $parentTab->module = $this->name;
    $parentTab->active = 1;
    $parentTab->id_parent = Tab::getIdFromClassName('SELL');
    $parentTab->icon = 'rocket';
    $parentTab->add();
```

You have to use the **controller=AdminShiprocketController** in the URL which is **wrong**. You need to **use controller=AdminShiprocket** to render the controller.

Also, add the controller file in **/modules/module_name/controllers/admin/**.

The **filename** should be: ***AdminShiprocketController.php***